# Android Offline tracking gives zigzag path

Tags: android, location, tracking

in my android application i need to track user location online and offline mode ,for this i am storing user's location coordinations in server and at admin retrieving those coordinates to draw path , online mode working fine but whereas i am getting this problem in offline mode , offline mode gps providing coordinates drawing the wrong path , how can i solve it please guide me .

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAJBM.jpg)

Comment: where is the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

If it's working on the online mode, I would suggest the following:

1. Verify that the timestamps of the offline locations are correctly
   saved and sent to your server. Use the `getTime` method on
   android.location.Location instances to get the right time. [Relevant
   docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime())
2. In offline mode, the accuracy of the data collected can be
   significantly affected, and you can evaluate whether the data collected 
   after verifying the previous point is accurate for your use-case.

Disclaimer: I work at [HyperTrack](https://hypertrack.com) and we build SDKs to get accurate location data and build live location features.